# HttpClient and LocalServerTestBase is really slow

Tags: performance, testing, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to write tests on a class that uses an `HttpClient` version `4.5`. The tests I wrote are really slow, so I tried to isolate the problem. I could write a test that demonstrate my issue :

```
public class RequeteurRESTTest extends LocalServerTestBase {

    private String startServer(String urlSuffix, HttpRequestHandler handler) throws Exception{
        this.serverBootstrap.registerHandler(urlSuffix, handler);
        HttpHost target = start();
        String serverUrl = "http://localhost:" + target.getPort();
        return serverUrl;
    }

    @Test
    public void testCase() throws Exception{
        String baseURL = startServer("/api", new HttpRequestHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,     HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
            }
        });

        HttpClient httpClient;
        httpClient = HttpClients.custom().build();

        HttpGet method = new HttpGet(baseURL + "/api");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the instruction:

```
httpClient.execute(method)
```

takes **10 seconds** to execute. This is very slow, but I can't figure out why this is so slow. Have I done any mistake in my test, or forgotten something?

Comment: Does it execute correctly ? i.e. does your server under test get invoked ?

Comment: The handler is correctly called, yes

Answer (score 0):

That is likely because you do nothing with the response object. At the very least one is supposed to close it.

Comment: What do you mean by "supposed to close it"?

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e145

Comment: Just followed the tuto, but seems not to be better. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

For a reason I can't understand, using the httpclient of the base class works fine, as follows:

```
@Test
public void testCase() throws Exception{
    String baseURL = startServer("/api", new HttpRequestHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,     HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
        }
    });

    HttpGet method = new HttpGet(baseURL + "/api");
    HttpResponse response = this.httpclient.execute(method);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of LocalServerTestBase class, you can see the following method :

```
@After
public void shutDown() throws Exception {
    if(this.httpclient != null) {
        this.httpclient.close();
    }

    if(this.server != null) {
        this.server.shutdown(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

By overriding this in you own test case you can set the timeout to 0 seconds. This should get rid of the delay you are seeing in execution.

Example implementation :

```
public class MyClassTest extends LocalServerTestBase{
    HttpHost httpHost;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
      super.setUp();
      this.serverBootstrap.registerHandler("/*", new HttpRequestHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) 
                          throws HttpException, IOException {
            System.out.println(request.getRequestLine().getMethod());
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);                
        }

      });

      httpHost = start();

    }

    @Test
    public void myMethodTest() throws Exception {
        //Create an instance and give the server url it should call
        MyClass instance = new MyClass(httpHost.toURI());
        //Test method that calls the server
        instance.myMethod();
    }

    @After @Override
    public void shutDown() throws Exception {
     if(this.httpclient != null) {
        this.httpclient.close();
     }
    if(this.server != null) {
        this.server.shutdown(0L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. The cause seems to be that the connections are not closed by the server after a request has completed. I'm not sure whether this is special behavior for testing or can also happen when you're communicating with a real server. In my Google searches I found that it is not common / easily supported to close the connection client side, leading me to believe this connection-not-closing is just testing behavior. When I set the test server to never reuse the connection it solved the 10s delay for me.

```
this.serverBootstrap.setConnectionReuseStrategy((response, context) -> false);
```